# Using rest django rest framework for creating new object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models

```
class Peri(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class PeriTask(models.Model):
    #fields
    peri = models.ForeignKey(Peri)
```

My serializers are the following

```
class PeriSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Peri
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'url', 'peritasks', 'customer')


class PeriTaskSerialiazer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tooth = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PeriTask
        fields = ('id', 'task_type', 'implant', 'furcation', 'bleeding1', 'bleeding2', 'bleeding3', 'plaque1', 'plaque2',
              'gingival_margin1', 'gingival_margin2', 'gingival_margin3', 'probing_depth1', 'probing_depth2',
              'probing_depth3', 'tooth', 'url', )
```

and my viewsets are

```
class PeriodontogrammaViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PeriSerializer
    queryset = Peri.objects.all()


class PeriTaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PeriTaskSerialiazer
    queryset = PeriTask.objects.all()
```

But when I try to create a new peri using the api it gives me the following integrity error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: peri_peri.customer_id
```

My json data that beeing posted are

```
{"date": "2014-12-17",
 "customer": 27
}
```

I haven't created a serializer for customer since I am not interested in having api for my other models.

Comment: It's a standard view set...will include it in intial post

Comment: Maybe you should post ``"customer_id": 27`` ?

Comment: No I get the same result with "customer_id"

Comment: yes yes sorry editing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your serializer, you've set the customer key to `read_only`:

```
customer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

Try setting it to `False` or just simply removing this whole line (which seems superfluous to me)

Comment: True...removing read_only did it. But is is it possible to make it read_only when on detail-view of peri's. I don't wan't this to be able to be edited with put request. Or is it all or nothing?

Comment: You are free to make as many serializer as you need. Why not having one `read_only` and not the other?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you be more specific if you please?